# Using Generating Functions (again) to Solve Recurrences

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Consider the recursion $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + (-1)^n$ where $a_0 = 2$

Then $A(x) = \sum a_n x^n$ = $2 + \sum a_n x^n$ shifting the index of summation.  The only next move I can think of is to now substitute $a_n = \sum (2a_{n-1} + (-1)^n)$ but I am not sure how this helps.  Derivatives don't seem too helpful here either.  Perhaps telescoping?  Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $a_{n + 1} = 2 a_n - (-1)^n$, and thus:
$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0}{z} = 2 A(z) - \frac{1}{1 + z}
$$

Comment: Hence $-A(z) = z(-1/(1+z) + a_0)$?

Comment: $A(z) = \dfrac{(a_0 -1) z + a_0}{1 - z - 2 z^2}$

Comment: How might one decompose that into a closed form?

Comment: Didn't you get the sign wrong? In the formulation of the question I see $a_{n+1}=2a_n+(-1)^n$.

Comment: Also, where did the -1/(1+z) come from?

Comment: @Stopwatch, $\sum_{n \ge 0} z^n = (1 - z)^{-1}$

Comment: @Matt, I shifted the index by one.

Comment: @Stopwatch, use partial fractions. That splits it into two geometric series.

Comment: @vonbrand, oh sure, I missed that one, sorry ...

Comment: I see, so then z + 2 has to correspond with $A/(z-1/2) + B/(z+1)$ so Az + A + Bz - B/2 $\to$ A + B = 1 and A - B/2 = 2.  Then we'll obtain B = 2/3 A = 1/3 so we have two geometric series whose coefficients will be the 'roots' of our characteristic equation?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to see the pattern:

$$a_1 = 2a_0 - 1\\
a_2 = 2\cdot 2 a_0 - 2 + 1\\
a_3 = 2\cdot 2\cdot 2a_0 - 2\cdot 2 + 2 - 1\\\vdots\\
a_n = 2^na_0 + (-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-2)^k$$
The sum can of course be written in closed form.